# retrieve specific data from the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Goal:
Retrieve data "aaa" from the first "td" in "tr" by pressing the link "info". For instance, if pressing the link "info" from the first "tr" I should retrieve the data "aaa" from the first "tr".

Problem:

> Having problem to find a solution to retrieve data "aaa" by pressing
>   the link "info" by using javascript AND jquery. In other word, how to
>   retrieve data by jquery and javascript

Please rememeber that I also need to transer the value aaa for other method in relation to business logic.

Another thing, The quantity of rows in the list can be changed everyday.

---

```
   <table border="1" SUMMARY="aaa" id="tblProjekt">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Projekt name</th>
            <th>Total time</th>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>comments</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td><a href='#' onclick='startPoint(); return false;'>info</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td><a href='#' onclick='startPoint(); return false;'>info</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td><a href='#' onclick='startPoint(); return false;'>info</a></td>
        </tr>      
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: You want to retrieve the value of the first cell in the same row the link is clicked? Am I correct? If so, do you know that you have only one row with links, and there are only links, no other data?

Comment: "You want to retrieve the value of the first cell in the same row the link is clicked? Am I correct?"

I have now provided right sourcecode.

Comment: Why do people insist on using an A element when the really don't want an A element? Just use a styled span or button element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree to 3nigma that the question is not clear. In case you wanted the link to appear in each row and display first cell's content after clicking it, here is the solution ([see jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYT75/)):

```
jQuery('#tblProjekt').delegate('a.startPoint', 'click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var info = jQuery(this).parents('tr').find('td:first-child').html();
    alert(info);
});
```

This will display alert popup with what I have just described. It assumes your HTML should look like this:

```
<table border="1" SUMMARY="aaa" id="tblProjekt">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Projekt name</th>
            <th>Total time</th>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>comments</th>
            <th>(link for more info)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa1</td>
            <td>aaa2</td>
            <td>aaa3</td>
            <td>aaa4</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="startPoint">info</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bbb1</td>
            <td>bbb2</td>
            <td>bbb3</td>
            <td>bbb4</td>
            <td><a href="#" class="startPoint">info</a></td>
        </tr>  
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Did it help? Is it what you needed?

Ps. I removed inline JavaScript from your code. Try to avoid this if possible.

Comment: I'm confused: he should try to avoid *what*, 'if possible'?

Comment: @David Thomas: Sorry for being not clear enough. He should avoid inline JavaScript, it is harder to maintain. Originally, he assigned `onclick` events in the anchor tag using "_Intrinsic events_" (for more please see [W3C document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html)).

Comment: On re-reading, it makes sense. I...don't know how, or why, I managed to miss the explanation. My apologies for being, apparently, clinically blind... =/

Answer (score 0):

your question was not clear to me but the following fiddle achieves  the goal specified in the question i.e. to retrieve `aaa`

```
$("a:contains('info')").click(function(){

var v = $("#tblProjekt >tbody> tr:first>td").html();
alert(v);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JKByC/1/

**EDIT**

for the updated html

```
$("a").click(function(){

    var v = $(this).closest("tr").children(':first-child').text();
    alert(v);

});
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sDZ7q/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am also unclear about the request.  But I think you might want something like this (to start you on your way..)

```
$('#oneColumnInfo').click(function(){
    var oneColumnText = $('tbody tr td:first').text();
    alert(oneColumnText);
    return false;
});

$('#twoColumnInfo').click(function(){
    var twoColumnText = $('tbody tr td:first').next().text();
    alert(twoColumnText);
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/eaSMS/

BTW, I removed the inline `click events`.

```
<table border="1" SUMMARY="aaa" id="tblProjekt">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Projekt name</th>
            <th>Total time</th>
            <th>Task</th>
            <th>comments</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>aaa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
            <td>bbb</td>
        </tr>      
        <tr>
            <td><a href='#' id="oneColumnInfo">info</a></td>
            <td><a href='#' id="twoColumnInfo">info</a></td>
            <td><a href='#'>info</a></td>
            <td><a href='#'>info</a></td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the amended html in the question, I'd suggest using:

```
$('td a').click(
    function(){
        var projektName = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text();
        alert(projektName);
        return false;
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/bUuaR/).

---

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find).
- `text()`.